# Camel routing with custom method

Tags: apache, filter, routes, apache-camel, esb

Im trying to route an object based on three different criteria.

My questions are:

1)why if I have the i.e. routing the object goes to one of the filters in a random way and not linear?

2)how should I do it if this does not work (the example), if I do it with "choice" and "when", can I use a custom method to route? like im using in filter in this example

Many thanks

Example shown:

```
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {                                  

    from("activemq:cfes.queue").filter().method(CustomCamelFilter.class, "methodOne")
        .to("file://c:/u01/tomcat_conf/folder1");               

    from("activemq:cfes.queue").filter().method(CustomCamelFilter.class, "methodTwo")
        .to("file://c:/u01/tomcat_conf/folder2");

    from("activemq:cfes.queue").filter().method(CustomCamelFilter.class, "methodThree")
        .to("file://c:/u01/tomcat_conf/folder3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect to use the `.filter()` pattern here, when it seems you indeed should use the `.choice()` pattern instead, like this:

```
.choice()
    .when(method(MyBean.class, "methodOne")).log("HELLO1")
    .when(method(MyBean.class, "methodTwo")).log("HELLO2")
    .when(method(MyBean.class, "methodThree")).log("HELLO3")
    .otherwise().log("OOPS!")
.end()
```